# PHP cURL says https not supported

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm making several cURL requests to a page.  After this one POST request, I get this error in my cURL output

```
* Protocol  https not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
```

cURL doesn't even make the request. I can't figure out how to solve this error.

The weird thing is that SSL is enabled for both my CLI and FPM.  Seen here http://cl.ly/image/1L062C2h2M2W

I tried making the request to an http:// instead of https://. That didn't change anything. I even tried making sure my server had an SSL, and that didn't change it.

My cURL calls look like this

```
$fp2 = fopen('cookies/debug.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp2, "\n $action");
fwrite($fp2, "\n $url");
fwrite($fp2, "\n ".sizeof($data));
fwrite($fp2, "\n ".json_encode($data));
fwrite($fp2, "\n_________________________________________\n");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
if($action == "POST") curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);

$fp = fopen('cookies/curl.txt', 'a');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->strCookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->strCookie);

    if($header) {
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    }

// Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
if($action == "POST") {

    if(in_array("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded", $header)) {
        $data = http_build_query($data);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}

// Get response from the server.
$res = curl_exec($ch);
fwrite($fp, "\n_________________________________________\n");
fwrite($fp, "\n$action $url\n");

return $res;
```

and the full debug of the last call is

```
______________about to try___________________________
POST  https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/communication-manager/view-message.html/ref=ag_xx__cmread?ie=UTF8&addnFilter0=rs&arrivalDate=1417064517&clcmResponseTimeSuboptions=uwd&curPage=1&dateExactEnd=&dateExactStart=&dateFilter=7d&isInbox=1&itemsPerPage=20&marketplaceId=ATVPDKIKX0DER&messageId=A3OSG68VXPA9BV&msgIndex=1&otherPartyId=&pageNum=1&replyToEmail=0&searchBoxText=&showFilters=0&sortBy=ArrivalDate&sortOrder=Descending&timestamp=1417070427&totalMsg=1&view=reader

* Protocol  https not supported or disabled in libcurl
* Closing connection -1
```

The "about to try", is my own debugging. The two ** are the only output from cURL when I try this request.

Comment: are you trying if from localhost or any domain?

Comment: It's from a rackspace server

Comment: Note, that other POSTs to https URLs to this domain work fine. It's just this one in particular.  In the browser when I monitor this request, it returns a 302 Moved temporarily. That's the only thing that I can think that might be in the way. http://cl.ly/image/1l3k1w3s2s3v

Comment: Even i use rackspace, Check if cloudflare is interfering, when i check my phpinfo for curl i find libssh2. maybe it is required

Comment: Hey i think there is a issue with post request, did you try using the amazon scratchpad, my link works for india https://mws.amazonservices.in/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: I need to make custom requests, the MWS API doesn't offer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Another crazy issue. If I string replace https for http. I get * Protocol  http not supported or disabled in libcurl. So these are false errors.

Comment: I added libssh2, still nothing http://cl.ly/image/0y0J1540101o

Answer (score 1):

There was a space in front of the "https".  The error was saying " https" is not supported.